# $? and background functions in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How does $? behaves with functions executing in background?

Imagine I have the following function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
doInBackground() {
    #We call a function
    someOtherFunction someParam
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        echo "was one"
    else
        echo "was not one"
    fi
}
```

And that I call it multiple times this way:

```
doInBackground &
doInBackground &
doInBackground &
doInBackground &
wait
```

If they are executing simultaneously, what will $? return? Will it be affected by the other executions? What is the behavior in this case?

Comment: `$?` is return/exit code of function `someOtherFunction` and you are executing `doInBackground` in background.

Comment: Voting this question up because I find it interesting and essential to understanding instances of shells and processes! Very good question!

Comment: As stated in the standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) : "The exit status of an asynchronous list shall be zero."  After you call `wait`, `$?` will be set appropriately.  But note that in your case, the exit status of `doInBackground` is the exit status of the if clause, which is the exit status of whichever `echo` that was called, which is probably 0 (`echo` can fail, but it probably won't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the program runs simultaneously, it is running by itself, therefore others have no impact on it. When you execute

```
someOtherFunction someParam
```

right after that `$?` holds the value of the function this script executed. Why? Adding `&` runs process in **new shell**, and different instances of shells do not comunicate between each other. It is like you would open few terminals and run `doInBackground` once in each terminal window.

To put it other way, let's say for example `sshd` is running, somebody logs in over `ssh` and the access log is getting stored. Right after it you would call `$?`, expecting to return the exit code of the process you ran, but `ssh` logging completed trillionth of a second after your program... Would it not be strange to get the exit status of `ssh` instead of your program? ;)

Comment: Thank you, very explanatory. The "Adding & runs process in new shell" is key.

Comment: Indeed it is. I am glad you understood the very key of my tiresomly long explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Emphasis: *"If **N** is not given ... the return code is zero."*

```
bash$ help wait
wait: wait [n]
    Wait for the specified process and report its termination status.  If
    N is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for,
    and the return code is zero.  N may be a process ID or a job
    specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in the job's
    pipeline are waited for.
```